# How can I make video of my running application?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to make an video recording option  in my application in cocos2d Iphone 
. How can we do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it in the simulator on your Mac and use a screen capturing tool (eg Screenflow or even Quicktime )